# Prestashop 1.7 template not pass variable

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have a problem that I can not solve.
in prestashop 1.7 I have a tpl file called product.tpl where inside, besides the various data, I call a file with the following code:

```
<div class="product-actions">
          {block name='product_buy'}
            <form action="{$urls.pages.cart}" method="post" id="add-to-cart-or-refresh">
              <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{$static_token}">
              <input type="hidden" name="id_product" value="{$product.id}" id="product_page_product_id">
              <input type="hidden" name="id_customization" value="{$product.customization_id}" id="product_customization_id">

              {block name='product_variants'}
                {include file='catalog/_partials/product-variants.tpl'}
              {/block}

              {block name='product_pack'}
                {if $packItems}
                  <section class="product-pack">
                    <h3 class="h4">{l s='This pack contains' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'}</h3>
                    {foreach from=$packItems item="product_pack"}
                      {block name='product_miniature'}
                        {include file='catalog/_partials/miniatures/pack-product.tpl' product=$product_pack}
                      {/block}
                    {/foreach}
                </section>
                {/if}
              {/block}

              {block name='product_discounts'}
                {include file='catalog/_partials/product-discounts.tpl'}
              {/block}

              {block name='product_add_to_cart'}
                {include file='catalog/_partials/product-add-to-cart.tpl'}
              {/block}

              {block name='product_additional_info'}
                {include file='catalog/_partials/product-additional-info.tpl'}
              {/block}

              {block name='product_refresh'}
                <input class="product-refresh ps-hidden-by-js" name="refresh" type="submit" value="{l s='Refresh' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}">
              {/block}
            </form>
          {/block}

        </div>
```

and everything works correctly.

what interests me most specifically is the portion of code referred to in this block

```
{block name='product_variants'}
                {include file='catalog/_partials/product-variants.tpl'}
              {/block}
```

The code is:

```
<div class="product-variants">
  {foreach from=$groups key=id_attribute_group item=group}
    <div class="clearfix product-variants-item">
      <span class="control-label">{$group.name}</span>
      {if $group.group_type == 'select'}
        <select
          class="form-control form-control-select"
          id="group_{$id_attribute_group}"
          data-product-attribute="{$id_attribute_group}"
          name="group[{$id_attribute_group}]">
          {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
            <option value="{$id_attribute}" title="{$group_attribute.name}"{if $group_attribute.selected} selected="selected"{/if}>{$group_attribute.name}</option>
          {/foreach}
        </select>
      {elseif $group.group_type == 'color'}
        <ul id="group_{$id_attribute_group}">
          {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
            <li class="float-xs-left input-container">
              <label>
                <input class="input-color" type="radio" data-product-attribute="{$id_attribute_group}" name="group[{$id_attribute_group}]" value="{$id_attribute}"{if $group_attribute.selected} checked="checked"{/if}>
                <span
                  {if $group_attribute.html_color_code}class="color" style="background-color: {$group_attribute.html_color_code}" {/if}
                  {if $group_attribute.texture}class="color texture" style="background-image: url({$group_attribute.texture})" {/if}
                ><span class="sr-only">{$group_attribute.name}</span></span>
              </label>
            </li>
          {/foreach}
        </ul>
      {elseif $group.group_type == 'radio'}
        <ul id="group_{$id_attribute_group}">
          {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
            <li class="input-container float-xs-left">
              <label>
                <input class="input-radio" type="radio" data-product-attribute="{$id_attribute_group}" name="group[{$id_attribute_group}]" value="{$id_attribute}"{if $group_attribute.selected} checked="checked"{/if}>
                <span class="radio-label">{$group_attribute.name}</span>
              </label>
            </li>
          {/foreach}
        </ul>
      {/if}
    </div>
  {/foreach}
</div>
```

then I modified the tpl file of the module ps_featuredproducts and inside the main file "ps_featuredproducts.tpl", inside the foreach I inserted a part of the code to display the variants and some product html design.

what happens is that I visualize perfectly the formatting but all the values ​​of the variants do not let me see them, specifically this portion of code does not work

```
<div class="product-variants">
  {foreach from=$groups key=id_attribute_group item=group}
    <div class="clearfix product-variants-item">
      <span class="control-label">{$group.name}</span>
      {if $group.group_type == 'select'}
        <select
          class="form-control form-control-select"
          id="group_{$id_attribute_group}"
          data-product-attribute="{$id_attribute_group}"
          name="group[{$id_attribute_group}]">
          {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
            <option value="{$id_attribute}" title="{$group_attribute.name}"{if $group_attribute.selected} selected="selected"{/if}>{$group_attribute.name}</option>
          {/foreach}
        </select>
      {elseif $group.group_type == 'color'}
        <ul id="group_{$id_attribute_group}">
          {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
            <li class="float-xs-left input-container">
              <label>
                <input class="input-color" type="radio" data-product-attribute="{$id_attribute_group}" name="group[{$id_attribute_group}]" value="{$id_attribute}"{if $group_attribute.selected} checked="checked"{/if}>
                <span
                  {if $group_attribute.html_color_code}class="color" style="background-color: {$group_attribute.html_color_code}" {/if}
                  {if $group_attribute.texture}class="color texture" style="background-image: url({$group_attribute.texture})" {/if}
                ><span class="sr-only">{$group_attribute.name}</span></span>
              </label>
            </li>
          {/foreach}
        </ul>
      {elseif $group.group_type == 'radio'}
        <ul id="group_{$id_attribute_group}">
          {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
            <li class="input-container float-xs-left">
              <label>
                <input class="input-radio" type="radio" data-product-attribute="{$id_attribute_group}" name="group[{$id_attribute_group}]" value="{$id_attribute}"{if $group_attribute.selected} checked="checked"{/if}>
                <span class="radio-label">{$group_attribute.name}</span>
              </label>
            </li>
          {/foreach}
        </ul>
      {/if}
    </div>
  {/foreach}
</div>
```

Obviously the same code in the product page recalls all the variables, while in the home where I recall the contents on the homepage I can not recover them. Where am I wrong? I put hands on prestashop only a few weeks ago and I think I have a  confused ideas.
I hope little I have been clear, thanks to those who have the patience to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `$groups` does not exist in ps_featuredproducts. You have to add it to the module if you want to use it on your home page.
In order to do that, you have to modify function `getWidgetVariables()` in `ps_featuredproducts.php` like this.

```
public function getWidgetVariables($hookName = null, array $configuration = [])
{
    $products = $this->getProducts();

    foreach ($products as &$product) {
        $product_object = new Product((int)$product['id_product']);
        $groups = array();

        $attributes_groups = $product_object->getAttributesGroups($this->context->language->id);
        if (is_array($attributes_groups) && $attributes_groups) {
            foreach ($attributes_groups as $k => $row) {
                if (!isset($groups[$row['id_attribute_group']])) {
                    $groups[$row['id_attribute_group']] = array(
                        'group_name' => $row['group_name'],
                        'name' => $row['public_group_name'],
                        'group_type' => $row['group_type'],
                        'default' => -1,
                    );
                }

                $groups[$row['id_attribute_group']]['attributes'][$row['id_attribute']] = array(
                    'name' => $row['attribute_name'],
                    'html_color_code' => $row['attribute_color'],
                    'texture' => (@filemtime(_PS_COL_IMG_DIR_.$row['id_attribute'].'.jpg')) ? _THEME_COL_DIR_.$row['id_attribute'].'.jpg' : '',
                    'selected' => (isset($product_for_template['attributes'][$row['id_attribute_group']]['id_attribute']) && $product_for_template['attributes'][$row['id_attribute_group']]['id_attribute'] == $row['id_attribute']) ? true : false,
                );

                if ($row['default_on'] && $groups[$row['id_attribute_group']]['default'] == -1) {
                    $groups[$row['id_attribute_group']]['default'] = (int) $row['id_attribute'];
                }
                if (!isset($groups[$row['id_attribute_group']]['attributes_quantity'][$row['id_attribute']])) {
                    $groups[$row['id_attribute_group']]['attributes_quantity'][$row['id_attribute']] = 0;
                }
                $groups[$row['id_attribute_group']]['attributes_quantity'][$row['id_attribute']] += (int) $row['quantity'];
            }

            // wash attributes list (if some attributes are unavailables and if allowed to wash it)
            if (!Product::isAvailableWhenOutOfStock($product_object->out_of_stock) && Configuration::get('PS_DISP_UNAVAILABLE_ATTR') == 0) {
                foreach ($groups as &$group) {
                    foreach ($group['attributes_quantity'] as $key => &$quantity) {
                        if ($quantity <= 0) {
                            unset($group['attributes'][$key]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $product['groups'] = $groups;
    }

    if (!empty($products)) {
        return array(
            'products' => $products,
            'allProductsLink' => Context::getContext()->link->getCategoryLink($this->getConfigFieldsValues()['HOME_FEATURED_CAT']),
        );
    }
    return false;
}
```

I am using here a part of the code from the function `ProductController::assignAttributesGroups()` to get only `$groups` variable.

Finally, in `ps_featuredproducts.tpl`, you have to replace:

```
  <div class="product-variants">
      {foreach from=$groups key=id_attribute_group item=group}
        <div class="clearfix product-variants-item">
```

By:

```
  <div class="product-variants">
      {foreach from=$product.groups key=id_attribute_group item=group}
        <div class="clearfix product-variants-item">
```

And then, all variables will be displayed like on product page.

Comment: Thank you so much, let's say that more or less everything works now because I can find the missing variables.
Obviously now, by cycling the single product in the home, the javascript file behaves (in the selection of the product variables) in the same way at the same time :) and I did not anticipate this. But I think the problem here should be solved by completely tweaking the javascript file because I can not see another solution.
Thank you again for giving me the solution

Answer (score 0):

The variable $groups that is used in `catalog/_partials/product-variants.tpl` is passed from PoductController.php and is available only on product info page. You cannot use it on your homepage or elsewhere. If you want to achieve the same result you need to create some similar variable within your module and pass it to your own template. The variable created in the file `controller/front/ProductController.php` within method `assignAttributesGroups` but it is pretty complicated I think you can create something much simpler.